# Pulling files from a Windows Mobile device via ActiveSync

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mobile, windows-mobile

I would like know how can I move a file from a my Handheld device to some Windows folder,  across the USB Sync. ej.

from a \MyDevice\some.txt copy to C:\Temp\some.txt in C# or VB or C++.

I'm new in develop in this device. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: what handheld device? windows mobile? iphone? andriod? why USB? Why not over wi-fi ? or internet? heard about dropbox?

Comment: THe device is a Windows Mobile device, and is across usb for what the Handheld must be connected in the PC., where the files should be copied.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming it's a Windows Mobile device; there's no other mobile devices (for now) that Visual C++ can be used with.

You cannot do it from the device side; allowing the mobile device to mess with the host's filesystem would be a huge security risk.

From the Windows side, you can use the RAPI functions `CeCopyFile()` or `CeCreateFile()/CeReadFile()`, when the device is connected to the PC via ActiveSync. Also you can pull files via the Core Connectivity API, but it's considerably more tricky; you'll have to use the CoreCon interface `ICcConnection`.

The RAPI header and library come with a Windows Mobile SDK, pretty much any version.

EDIT: so you need it from the device side. No built-in API for that. Consider ActiveSync. It has an interface for automatically syncing a host folder with a device folder; if the files change on the device, the changes will be automatically pulled to the PC. If you implement a custom item interface, you can notify ActiveSync of changes as they happen.

Think of it this way. Pushing files with no active cooperation from the host PC is impossible; you gotta realize how much of a disaster it would be otherwise; anyone with a device and a USB cable would be able to take over an arbitrary PC by just plugging the device in. But, if you're working on getting cooperation from a host PC, you might as well put together a RAPI program for Windows that polls a certain folder on the device and pulls files.

Or you can set up an FTP server on the host PC, like ctacke suggests.

Comment: means that from the handheld no way to move these files, Because I am bound to push the files from the device. :'(

Answer (score 1):

If you need to push from the device to the PC, you'll have to have a service on the PC running to accept the request and data, for example an FTP server.  When connected, you get a local virtual network and resolving "ppp_peer" will get you the connected PC.  At that point you could push to a local web service, FTP or whatever.  There's no way to transfer it directly to the file system without some explicit service, however, because that would be a gigantic security hole.